# CSS isn't working with ASP MVC project

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2013

I Created a simple ASP MVC View  but when i try to use Sass nothing happen in firefox or chrome. when i inspected the page in Chrome the following error appeared:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:29120/Views/UI/test.css
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

And network response is

```
 <head>
        <title>The resource cannot be found.</title>
    enter code here
</head>
<body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>The resource cannot be found.</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. &nbsp;Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
            <br><br>

            <b> Requested URL: </b>/Views/UI/test.css<br><br>

            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

            <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34212

            </font>

    </body>
<!-- 
[HttpException]: Path &#39;/Views/UI/test.css&#39; was not found.
   at System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
-->
```

Index.cshtml

```
<head>
 <link href="~/Views/UI/test.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<title>title</title>
</head>
```

I checked IIS directory and the file does exist.

Currently I'm using MVS 2013 Ultimate Update 4, so any idea why it's not working?

Comment: How are you compiling the Sass?

Comment: Using visual studio, it does automated compilation to css

Comment: If the Sass compiles correctly, this is not a Sass problem.  It sounds like you're either using the wrong path to the CSS or it isn't being served correctly.

Comment: it's the correct path i already dragged and dropped it to be sure, How to check if it's served correctly or not?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the 404 response could be because you have the css file within a subdirectory of Views.

By default, all files within the Views folder aren't served due to the `web.config` in the Views folder containing this setting under `<system.web>`:

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

You could change the above setting but I would recommend moving your sass and css out into a higher level directory.

More here: [Haacked article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/06/25/aspnetmvc-block-view-access.aspx/)

Comment: It worked but when i moved the css into another folder(~/Content/test.css). so the error didn't just happen because it was in sub-directory of Views, it happened because it was in Views folder or so it seems.